# Hazard Maps shape files that are not in NAMRIA, LiPAD, and PhilGIS (Philippines)

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, geohazard, data-mapping

Where should I find those updated shapefiles necessary for creating Hazard Maps?

I'm about to create Hazard Maps for San Pascual, Batangas, Philippines but I am having a hard time looking for resources.

As of now, I only have shapefiles for:

- Flood Susceptibility Map
- Rain-induced Landslide  and
- Storm Surge.

Comment: You should list the shapefiles that you need instead of the ones you already have.